# Distinguish view by background colors

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to distinguish the background color of a view but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me to accomplish the task.

Below is my DatabaseHelper.java class

```
public  List<HouseModal> get_Working_Area_Structures_House(int limit, int offset,String searched_Str) {
    if(database == null){
        database = getWritableDatabase();
    }
    List<HouseModal> list_krd= new ArrayList<>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT\n" +
            "\tWAS.Para_Structure_ID,\n" +
            "\tWAS.Para_Code || '   ' || CAST (WAS.Structure_No AS int) AS Structure_No,\n" +
            "\tST.Family_Count AS Families,\n" +
            "\tFM.Family_Members_Count AS Family_Members, \n" +
            "\t FM.Family_Migration AS Family_Migration\n" +
            "FROM\n" +
            "\t (\n" +
            "\t\t SELECT\n" +
            "\t\t\tP.Para_Code,\n" +
            "\t\t\tPS.Para_Structure_ID,\n" +
            "\t\t\tPS.Structure_No \n" +
            "\t\tFROM\n" +
            "\t\t\tPara_Structure AS PS\n" +
            "\t\tINNER JOIN  Working_Area_Structures AS WAS ON PS.Para_Structure_ID = WAS.Para_Structure_ID\n" +
            "\t\tINNER JOIN  Field_Station_Paras AS P ON PS.Para_ID = P.Para_ID \n" +
            "\t) AS WAS,\n" +
            "\t (\n" +
            "\tSELECT\n" +
            "\t\t\tKH.Para_Structure_ID,\n" +
            "\t\t\tCOUNT(DISTINCT KH.House_Hold_ID) AS Family_Count \n" +
            "\t\tFROM\n" +
            "\t\t\tKhandan_Register_Header AS KH\n" +
            "\t\tLEFT JOIN  Family_Visit_History AS FVH ON KH.House_Hold_ID = FVH.House_Hold_ID \n" +
            "\t\tWHERE\n" +
            "\t\t(FVH.Visit_Status = 0 OR FVH.Visit_Status IS NULL)\n" +
            "\t\t--AND ((date(FVH.Visit_Date) >= (SELECT date(Starting_Date) FROM Working_Cycle WHERE DATE('NOW') BETWEEN date(Starting_Date)AND date(Ending_Date)) AND date(FVH.Visit_Date) <= (SELECT date(Ending_Date) FROM Working_Cycle WHERE DATE('NOW') BETWEEN date(Starting_Date)AND date(Ending_Date))) OR date(FVH.Visit_Date) IS NULL) \n" +
            "\t\t--AND (KH.House_Hold_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT House_Hold_ID FROM Family_Visit_History WHERE Visit_Status = 1)) \n" +
            "\t\tGROUP BY KH.Para_Structure_ID\n" +
            "\t) AS ST , (\n" +
            "\t\t SELECT\n" +
            "\t\t\tKH.Para_Structure_ID,\n" +
            "\t\t\tCOUNT(\n" +
            "\t\t\t\tDISTINCT KD.Family_Member_ID\n" +
            "\t\t\t) AS Family_Members_Count, \n" +
            "\t\t\tfmr.Family_Migration_ID AS Family_Migration \n" +
            "\t\tFROM\n" +
            "\t\t\tKhandan_Register_Detail AS KD\n" +
            "\t\tINNER JOIN  Khandan_Register_Header AS KH ON KD.House_Hold_ID = KH.House_Hold_ID\n" +
            "\t\tLEFT JOIN  Family_Visit_History AS FVH ON KH.House_Hold_ID = FVH.House_Hold_ID \n" +
            "\t\tleft join Family_Migration_Register as fmr on KH.House_Hold_ID = fmr.House_Hold_ID \n" +
            "\t\tWHERE\n" +
            "\t\t\t(\n" +
            "\t\t\t\tFVH.Visit_Status = 0\n" +
            "\t\t\t\tOR FVH.Visit_Status IS NULL\n" +
            "\t\t\t) \n" +
            "\t\t--AND ((date(FVH.Visit_Date) >= (SELECT date(Starting_Date)FROM Working_Cycle WHERE DATE('NOW') BETWEEN date(Starting_Date)AND date(Ending_Date)) \n" +
            "\t\t--AND date(FVH.Visit_Date) <= (SELECT date(Ending_Date) FROM Working_Cycle WHERE DATE('NOW') BETWEEN date(Starting_Date)AND date(Ending_Date))) OR date(FVH.Visit_Date) IS NULL) \n" +
            "\t\tAND (KH.House_Hold_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT House_Hold_ID FROM Family_Visit_History WHERE Visit_Status = 1 )) \n" +
            "\t\tGROUP BY\n" +
            "\t\t\tKH.Para_Structure_ID \n" +
            "\t) AS FM \n" +
            "WHERE\n" +
            "\tWAS.Para_Structure_ID = ST.Para_Structure_ID \n" +
            "\n" +
            "AND WAS.Para_Structure_ID = FM.Para_Structure_ID\n" +
            "\n" +
            "AND ST.Para_Structure_ID = FM.Para_Structure_ID\n" +
            "\n";
    if (!searched_Str.trim().equals("null") && !searched_Str.trim().equals(""))
    {
        selectQuery += " And WAS.Structure_No like '%"+searched_Str+"%'";
    }
    selectQuery += " ORDER BY WAS.Para_Code, Cast(WAS.Structure_No As int) limit "+limit+" offset "+offset;

    try{
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    HouseModal dkrd = new HouseModal();
                    dkrd.setStructureID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    dkrd.setStructureNo(cursor.getString(1));
                    dkrd.setFamilies(cursor.getInt(2));
                    dkrd.setMembers(cursor.getInt(3));
                    dkrd.setFamilyMigrationID(cursor.getString(4));
                    list_krd.add(dkrd);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list_krd;
}
```

This is my modal class

```
package pk.softech.sukh.modal;

public class HouseModal {

    private int structureID, families,members;
    private String migrationID;

    private String houseHoldID;
    private String structureNo ;


    public String getFamilyMigrationID() {
        return migrationID;
    }

    public void setFamilyMigrationID(String newMigrationID) {
        this.migrationID = newMigrationID;
    }

    public String getStructureNo() {
        return structureNo;
    }

    public void setStructureNo(String structureNo) {
        this.structureNo = structureNo;
    }


    public int getStructureID() {
        return structureID;
    }

    public void setStructureID(int structureID) {
        this.structureID = structureID;
    }

    public int getFamilies() {
        return families;
    }

    public void setFamilies(int families) {
        this.families = families;
    }

    public int getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(int members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public String getHouseHoldID() {
        return houseHoldID;
    }

    public void setHouseHoldID(String houseHoldID) {
        this.houseHoldID = houseHoldID;
    }
}
```

below is my adapter code, I'm getting data in a getter "getFamilyMigrationID". So the scenario is if this getter has a "null value" it will give a light gray background or in else condition if this getter has a value so it will give a light yellow background. I'm doing a mistake but don't know what the mistake is?

```
package pk.softech.sukh.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import pk.softech.sukh.R;
import pk.softech.sukh.modal.HouseModal;

public class HouseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HouseModal> {

    public HouseAdapter(Context context,List<HouseModal> items) {
        super(context,R.layout.view_house_item,items);
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView totalAfrad,totalKhandan,structureID,migratedFamilies;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        HouseModal item = getItem(position);
        if(view == null){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_house_item,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.structureID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.structureID);
            holder.totalAfrad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalAfrad);
            holder.totalKhandan = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalKhandan);
            holder.migratedFamilies = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.families);

            if(item.getFamilyMigrationID() == null){
                view.findViewById(R.id.structureID).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CFD8DC")); //light gray
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.structureID).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDFDE9")); //light yellow
            }

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.structureID.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStructureNo()));
        holder.totalKhandan.setText(String.valueOf(item.getFamilies()));
        holder.totalAfrad.setText(String.valueOf(item.getMembers()));
        holder.migratedFamilies.setText(String.valueOf(item.getFamilyMigrationID()));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: `I want to distinguish the background color ...` what has this question to do with the database code you provided? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @KlingKlang To let the people know how I am receiving values from DB

Comment: Does it make any sense to you? You want to get the **background color** of an ImageView... or something. Who cares that your app is **also** connecting to some database? That appears to be **very marginal and not related at all** with your question.

Comment: You are not understanding the question..first read it carefully please

Comment: Maybe "distinguish" is not the correct verb here. Should it be "determine the background color of a view"? And even then it's unclear based on what you would "determine" it. (Apparently based on the values queried from the database, but it's not really clear from the text. Maybe it's clear if one goes through all the code, but that's awkward.)

Comment: Maybe you're not explaining yourself clearly. Don't start with the idea that others are stupid, if they don't understand what you mean. It's just that we don't live in your brain.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen I'm a newbie developer and this is my 2nd question on the Stack Overflow

Comment: For what I see (and maybe this dissolves some clouds from your vision of the thing), you are comparing objects (not values) to *null* (which is actually "nothing"). Now this won't help you by any means. Be aware that ***null*** is a wild beast and needs to be handled properly.

Comment: And we are trying to be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

if your item is null how it is possible to change the color of it or how even possible to check it?

> null is null.

you should Check Null for safety of Crashes not changing the color.
if you want Change color you should get a specific field from your database that shows this column has no value in it or its empty.
then you can check for its Color

Comment: If my item has a value 1234 == null. So definitely it will not be equal to null

Comment: ok you are answering it yourself.your item has a value and you can show it.if an item does not have a value how you want to show it?its not standard

Comment: But I'm not getting the desired result, I have values in DB but the code always get to the IF condition like all the datasets are null which is not true

Comment: ok i think i found out your problem...you are calling your condition in getview...you should call it even in onBindViewHolder or a method in ViewHolderClass with view and return in in onBindViewHolder...getView Will check your condition One Time and apply it for all of your items.let me Know

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if(holder.structureID.isEmpty(){
                view.findViewById(R.id.structureID).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CFD8DC")); //light gray
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.structureID).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FDFDE9")); //light yellow
            }
```

Outside of the if(view == null) and into the else block, so that it gets the change when it is redrawn because recyclerview will reuse the cells and anything that needs to be changed (text, values, colours) will need to be re-applied also

Edit : just to clarify - you will need your previous “colour changing if statement” in the if block still due to the way you have set it out, if you change the getView() method around so that you are only setting values for the viewHolder object in your if/else statement and then below that you change all the values you require on the view itself it will end up being cleaner and easier to read